# How to "Delete derived data" in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator

In **Xcode5** there is simple option to Delete derived data:

In organiser menu (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>):

[image]

But with new interface of Xcode6 there is no similar options.

Is there any quick methods to delete this trough **Xcode6** interface?

Or now I should remove this folders in system manually?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> In Xcode 6 will present Devices, which is separated from **Organizer**. Instead you can go **Window**, then **Organizer**, then find your project in **Projects** to delete derived data. You may set a short key in Key Bindings for quick access to derived data.

[image]

Comment: That's silly. Why not shortcut it to cmd+shift+3 at least? I used that shortcut all the time, mostly for Projects and Archives.

Comment: This is outdated as of Xcode 6.3. See k k 's answer below.

Answer (score 127):

Update again: in Xcode 12 go to Preferences -> Locations tab -> click the arrow by the DerivedData path to open it in Finder -> move DerivedData to the trash (Xcode will rebuild it)

Comment: For XCode 12, the equivalent appears to be Product | Clean Build Folder. Then build and run again. That worked for me. I'd added items to AppIcon in Assets.xcassets after having already built once, and the icon appeared in the dock after Product | Clean Build Folder.

Answer (score 59):

exit xcode

In the Terminal application (I'm sure you have it open at all times ;^) type:

rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

If xcode does not cooperate when you asked it politely to exit
from file menu or via Command-Q shortcut <s>due to
some incessant popup craving for your attention in a pile of windows in a long forgotten space</s> you could brute force the xcode eviction like so

killall Xcode; rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Caveat: if you won't exit the xcode first you'd get lingering files (courtesy of HFS I suppose)
and you'd have to use the Sheamus'es script. Feel free to share your experience with the newer (no longer experimental) macos fs in the comments below.

bash tip of the day: *tab performs filename completion as you type paths*

Tip of the year: consider procuring O'Reilly bash book[s] to save your time further. Disclaimer: I do not work for O'Reilly, never did. Just a happy
customer.

Though in my recent experience with Xcode 10.2.1 Windows(Cmd)+Shift+k shortcut works just fine.

Comment: Is there a morale issue at Apple? I do this at least once a day so that xcode opens again. XCode 8 has been amazingly bad.

Answer (score 34):

At Xcode 7.2.1 you can now the following:

<kbd>⌘⌥⇧K</kbd>

Which is <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Alternatively you can select Product > (Hold <kbd>⌥</kbd> Key) and select Clean Build Folder...

**Edit:**
I also like to create an alias for one of @anton-tropashko's suggested shell commands:

```
alias nuke-dd='rm -rv ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData'
```

Add this ^^ to your `~/.bash_profile` or somewhere else that is sourced for each shell you start, then just type:

```
$ nuke-dd
```

Comment: its really helpful.

Answer (score 9):

The approach I'm using is to install the watchdog app ([https://www.cerebralgardens.com/watchdog)](https://www.cerebralgardens.com/watchdog).

This app will automatically clear your derived data based on your preferences (e.g. when data exceeds a certain size, when xcode closes, daily at a certain time, manually or when a clean is detected).

**EDIT:**

For those who don't want to spend money, in Xcode 7 select the Windows menu and Project. You can then select your project and delete its derived data (see screenshot below). Note that if there is a blue dot next to your project it indicates that it is open. It is better to close your project before deleting the derived data.

[image: Delete derived data]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to install the plugin *DerivedData Exterminator* by Alcatraz to clean up in Xcode6/7.

[image]

Please see the [deriveddata-exterminator on GitHub](https://github.com/kattrali/deriveddata-exterminator).

=====  Update  =====

In Xcode8:

Window -> Projects (sometimes *Projects* disappears,try it again, maybe a bug)
Choose your project,then click the delete button.

Or using Alfred:

http://www.packal.org/workflow/xcode-cache-clean

just type xcl.

[image: xcode-cache-clean]

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 7.3

```
Window -> Projects
```

Then Delete the Derived Data

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line. My [shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27977848/1231948), works for Xcode 4, 5, and 6.

Sometimes, simply calling rm -rf on the Derived Data directory leaves a lingering file or two, but my script loops until all files are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
Then in terminal,  type purgeallbuilds, and all subfolders of DerivedData are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I have hit on `Delete` button  on DerivedData in (**Window -> Projects**) but it doesn't work.

Then I solve it by click on **this small icon** [image] on the right of `DerivedData` path. It will navigate me to the `DerivedData` folder.
And in `DerivedData`, I remove `DerivedData` by Move To Trash and it removes successfully

Answer (score 0):

You can delete derived data by clicking on the going into Xcode > Preferences.
See the tutorial I found below.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ueEMGXKDBAc

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUnUH.jpg) shows a screenshot from the video which will guide you the exact location in Xcode preferences.

Comment: Please add relevant details to your answer and not just post a link. See the accepted answer for guidance and [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) which suggests: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."