# Xcode 6.1 Suddenly show error in all my projects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6.1

[image]

[image]

I have Copy a project folder from github into my new project But it's show some error.

So I have deleted that project(Deleted my new project too).

But suddenly xcode 6.1 show build error when i run in device for all my project also all in files.
like attached images.

I dont know why it's happened.

Hope someone try to resolve this!

Comment: I think you deleted any framework accidentally, so check  for framework i.e. Security Framework..

Comment: If all your projects are giving error maybe something got messed up in derived data. Try clearing that up by using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039932/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode6

Comment: But its show an error all my projects's all files , also Build phases not show any library with name  security . FYI: There is no error when run with simulator.

Comment: Then try to Cleanup your xcode derived  Data  go to --->OS X Mavericks ▸ Users ▸ your system ▸ Library ▸ Developer ▸ Xcode ▸ DerivedData

Comment: hi @Jitendra i have cleared derived data from xcode menu Window->Organisor->projects and remove all items after restart xcode but its not done.

Comment: @Mohanraj - Please attach a zoomed in screenshot so that the error is visible. What exact error are you getting?

Comment: Hi @z22 , please have a look my edited question.

Comment: try adding security framework again

Comment: I cant able to add Security frame work because its not show in build phases search after click + button.

Comment: @Mohanraj please check this path for security framework ,if unavailable then add security framework there and then add on your project from build phase...     Path-->     Applications ▸ Xcode  ▸ Contents ▸ Developer ▸ Platforms ▸ iPhoneOS.platform ▸ Developer ▸ SDKs ▸ iPhoneOS.sdk ▸ System ▸ Library ▸ Frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Your first error:

> Security/Security.h not found

Means that you need Security.Framework, seems you are removed it.
For the rest errors it is seems you are removed Foundation.framework.

If you are using RCS(svn, git)(if not, I strongly recommend to start using it) , and you don't done any major changes, I will suggest to revert your last changes.

Comment: Hi @IAmDav I have add Foundation.framework to Build phases.  but cant find Security.Framework by seraching. also i have checked with old projects and there also the same issue as Build error .

Comment: Hi @Mohanraj, What you mean by "old proejcts"? Do you have any working state of your app? then revert local changes.
Do you getting the same errors after adding Foundation,framework?

Comment: The Security.Framework in the iOS framework, so you can find it by typing the name, ,after + button in embedded binaries.

Comment: old project means before meet this issue has some working projects, they also produce same build error when i ht run button.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to every one to help me,

In this issue was happened even i am create a new project

But I have some work to continue , so simply i was reinstall my xcode application and its work now.