# Apple Mach-0 Linker Error after changing project's name

Tags: xcode6

I read similar questions on SO which seem to be related to deleting derived data:  [How to "Delete derived data" in Xcode6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039932/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode6).  I've done this but still can't clear this error:  this is what I'm getting:

ld: file not found: /Users/garysabo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Maryland_Buyer_Costs-grvgfnvxkgteejglvsmhuklmfyzh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TitleCalc.app/TitleCalc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I changed the name from TitleCalc to Maryland Buyer Costs, this is what is in the /Users/garysabo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Maryland_Buyer_Costs-grvgfnvxkgteejglvsmhuklmfyzh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator folder?

[image]

Comment: Have you examined `...DerivedData/Maryland_Buyer_Costs-grvgfnvxkgteejglvsmhuklmfyzh/Build/Products...` to see what *is* there?  You changed the project name but what about the target build settings?  What are they producing?

Comment: I did, see my edit...so what should I do?

Comment: Note to anyone else, don't EVER change the projects name...it's not worth it.  Thankfully my app was pretty small so  I created a new project and copied the code and rearranged the storyboard.