# Add New Files in Xcode are not given an option for a Group or Target

Tags: xcode

[image: Here is an example of what I am shown when I try to add a new file to my project]

I am not 100% positive as to why Xcode is doing this, but it is very frustrating because I then have to manually add those files to the project and only then am I able to add its group/target.

Comment: Having the same issue… started happening to a project about a month ago

Comment: Not seen this particular one before but [deleting derived data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24039932/2466193) can fix odd project problems and is worth a try if you have not already.

Comment: I think the issue is mostly if you were on a beta build of xcode 7 and el capitain. I rolled my OS back to Yosemite and I haven't experienced this issue since.

Comment: Seeing the same thing here :\

Answer (score 6):

It is a bug on the new Xcode. This forum has a question very similar to yours, and I believe you'll find it useful: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5162