# Setting the initial window size of an app on OS X?

Tags: macos, storyboard, window

I'm using Xcode 7 on Yosemite. I created a new OS X application, and it came with a storyboard. When I launch the app, the app window is tiny.

What is the easiest way to set the default window size when the app launches?

Ideally I'm looking for a storyboard solution, not a programatic solution. However, if one does not exist, then a programatic solution will suffice. I **don't want to set the minimum/maximum size** of the window; the user should be able to size it as they see fit.

Answer (score 33):

I figured it out...

You need to change the initial View Controller's View (`NSView`) size to whatever you want in the Size Inspector. You do not need to touch the Window Controller nor the Window.

**Important**: Don't forget to delete [Xcode's derived data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039932/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode6); otherwise it will remember the previous value that was used the first time the app was run.

Comment: Did you set the frame of the view? In which part of the view cycle?

Comment: He means set the size of the view in Interface builder: Select the view, and got to Size Inspector (ruler icon). This works.

Comment: it doesn't have this ruler icon and Size Inspector anymore. Apple as always change interfaces every version in such way...

Answer (score 5):

Upon the view loading, so in the viewDidLoad method you can place either a call to a function or a line of code that looks like this :

```
self.view.window?.setFrame(NSRect(x:0,y:0,width: 1440,height: 790), display: true)
```

This will set your initial view to the NSRect you specify and display it.

Comment: (lldb) po self.view.window \n
nil