# unable to find utility "bitcode_strip", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: xcode

compile error after update xcode7.1.1

xcrun: error: unable to find utility "bitcode_strip", not a developer tool or in PATH

*** error: Couldn't copy and strip bitcode /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib to /Users/sungrow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iSolarCloud-dwdjvlyodazrbjayoqquublxncwp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/iSolarCloud.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: bitcode_strip failed with exit code 72

Comment: can you elaborate it more?

Comment: I have setting as https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12443，it still didn't work on phone, but on simulator is normal.

Comment: Setting STRIP_BITCODE_FROM_COPIED_FILES=NO did not solve my problem. Also note that this problem only appears for "Swift Mac App". Every thing else is working fine
This problem is only for my login. I tried creating new user and every thing was working fine

Comment: Any advancements made here? Same issue on my side - everything else working fine in software simulator

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the reason isn't building it with bitcode enabled.There may be something wrong with Xcode.You can try:

1. Clear derived data(Include Product->Clean).
2. Restart Xcode.

PS:My answer of how to clear derived data:

[How to "Delete derived data" in Xcode6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039932/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode6/35449758#35449758)

If it helps, please vote it up.I need enough reputations to post image...

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to deactivate BTICODE for Debug configuration. Go to 'Build Settings', search for 'ENABLE_BITCODE', drill down this option, and select 'NO' for Debug.