# Xcode keep installing older application code version on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I developed iOS application and archived it then push it to the App Store. Now I made some changes on the code and normally builds it and install it on the connected device, but the changes made on the code NOT reflected on the installed app while the installed app is the same as the pushed version to the App Store.

I tried to clean and build, deleted the app from the device, changed the build version, the app version, and the bundle identifier. and still the same.

NOTE: I am using ionic framework

So, do I missed something here?

Comment: maybe due to derived data? Check out here about how to clean derived data in xcode and see if it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039932/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode6

Comment: @zhaow thanks dude, but still not solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I found in config.xml file that  'id' is differ than the bundle identifier of the application. So, when I made the id same as the bundle identifier it works.