# Error Launching "WatchApp Extension" Install of Apple Watch Application never finished

Tags: xcode, xcode7, watchos-2

First time i add WatchKit extension it was working fine, and then i remove all the `watch app` target and files.

but now i add the `watch app` to my project again, but i got that error when i try to run the app.

i already try to clean, uninstall the app, restart xcode and simulator, turn on and turn off keychain, switch off and on in Apple Watch app. all those solution doesn't work, i don't have any idea how to fix it,what should i do?

thanks.

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: i don't know what is the error, i just add target>watchkit>scheme activate>run and the then "Error Launching “WatchApp Extension” Install of Apple Watch Application never finished" appear

Comment: As far as I remember: reboot your devices, including your mac. you might also delete the derived data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039932/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode6