# Xcode 8.1 and iOS 10.1.1 not building

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10, xcode8

Setup: 
iPhone 5c (iOS 10.0.2)
iPhone 6 plus (iOS 10.1.1)
iPad Air (iOS 10.1.1)
Xcode 8.1

I am currently building an app and it was building fine on all my devices.  I updated my 6 plus from 10.0.2 to 10.1.1 and now the app does not build. I the built on the iPad which was 10.0.2 and it succeeded and updated that. Failed also after update.

I get the following warnings and errors ... if anyone has any idea I'd appreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

```
Showing Recent Issues
ld: warning: ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Give_It_Up_and_Trade-efbegnisuhotnyharswslfockoid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libFMDB.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /Users/jb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Give_It_Up_and_Trade-efbegnisuhotnyharswslfockoid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libFMDB.aignoring file /Users/jb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Give_It_Up_and_Trade-efbegnisuhotnyharswslfockoid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libFontAwesomeKit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /Users/jb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Give_It_Up_and_Trade-efbegnisuhotnyharswslfockoid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libFontAwesomeKit.aignoring file /Users/jb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Give_It_Up_and_Trade-efbegnisuhotnyharswslfockoid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libAFNetworking.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /Users/jb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Give_It_Up_and_Trade-efbegnisuhotnyharswslfockoid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libAFNetworking.a


ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Give_It_Up_and_Trade-efbegnisuhotnyharswslfockoid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRMStore.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /Users/jb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Give_It_Up_and_Trade-efbegnisuhotnyharswslfockoid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRMStore.a


ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Give_It_Up_and_Trade-efbegnisuhotnyharswslfockoid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libUIColor-Crayola.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /Users/jb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Give_It_Up_and_Trade-efbegnisuhotnyharswslfockoid/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libUIColor-Crayola.a


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMStore", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in iapClass.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMAppReceipt", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in iapClass.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FAKFontAwesome", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in browseViewController.o


      objc-class-ref in FirstViewController.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONRequestSerializer", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in networkingClass.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in networkingClass.o


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are you on the latest Xcode beta?

Comment: no I am on the official 8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solved it for me:

exit xcode

rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31512479/1178692

Answer (score 0):

If your Architectures and Valid Architectures are all right, you may check whether you have add $(inherited) to Other Linker Flags [like explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar error ...

Go to your Project Navigator from Xcode --> Bluid Settings ...

and "Filter" or "Search" by "No Common Blocks". The status are "YES", but set it to NO.

[image]

This change work for me. :)